# menu icons looking different on IOS than in ANDROID - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Added three icons on my ionic `home.html` using the below code. Problem is they are looking very dis-aligned and very small in size on IOS.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar color="headercolor" style="height:25px;">
    <ion-title style="text-align:center;font-size:11px;margin-top:20px;">Tags</ion-title>

    <button ion-button (click)="back()" style="background-color:transparent;margin-top:-50px;">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-back" class="icon"  style="color: #ffffff;font-size:20px;"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="home()">
        <ion-icon name="home" class="icon" style="font-size:16px;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="mailto()">
        <ion-icon name="mail" class="icon"  style="color: #ffffff;font-size:16px;"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="msg()">
        <ion-icon name="chatboxes" class="icon" style="color: #ffffff;font-size:17px;" ></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="close()">
        <ion-icon name="close" class="icon" style="color: #ffffff;font-size:16px;"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

What is the problem in my code and how can I fix this?

Below first screenshot is of Android and second screenshot is of iOS.

**Android screenshot**

[image]

**iOS screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is the default icon for ios and android, so if you want to use same icon for both platform then use this: `md-arrow-round-back`

Now Android back button will be used for both platforms.
In the Android back button you can see a border. It can be removed by `box-shadow:none`.

For Alignment use `<ion-row>` -> all elements will be aligned

To increase the icon size use `font-size` property in the `icon` tag. The icon size will be increased too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm still confused. I don't want to make any changes in code as it looks fine on android,  do I need to use differ icons for ios , or increase font size, ion row on ios side on all my pages ?

Comment: android has different icon  for back and ios has different icon for so you want to use same icon for ios and android
<ion-icon name="md-arrow-back"></ion-icon>

<!--Basic: auto-select the icon based on the platform -->
  <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>